# How to create a method to count characters in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

So I have a method that creates an array of 100 randomly generated characters.

Here it is:

```
//method to generate random character between ch1 and ch2
   public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2)
   {

      return (char) (ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 -ch1 +1));

   }

//==========================================   

   //method to assign generated characters (between a and z) to a 100 character array
   public static char[] createArray()
   {

      //declare a 100 character array
      char[] character = new char[100];

      //for loop assigning the random characters to the array using getRandomCharacter method
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      character[x] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');

      //for loop outputting the characters in the array
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      System.out.println(character[x]);

      return character;

   }
```

Now I need to create a method that takes the 100 generated characters, and counts how many times each vowel was generated. I am stuck with this one.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void countArray()
   {

      int vowelA, vowelE, vowelI, vowelO, vowelU, vowelY;
      int elsePlaceHolder = 0;

      for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
      {

         if ((createArray()) == ('a'))
         vowelA++;

         else if ((createArray()) == ('e'))
         vowelE++;

         else if ((createArray()) == ('i'))
         vowelI++;

         else if ((createArray()) == ('o'))
         vowelO++;

         else if ((createArray()) == ('u'))
         vowelU++;

         else if ((createArray()) == ('y'))
         vowelY++;

         else
         elsePlaceHolder++;

      }
```

I believe I am correct with using a for loop to do this, but I don't think I'm executing it correctly. Once that executes I can display the amount of times the vowels were counted by using the int variables. That elsePlaceHolder variable is there because I did not know what to do with the else statement.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with my `countArray()` method? It would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should modify the above code to this !

```
public static void countArray()
{

  int vowelA=0, vowelE=0, vowelI=0, vowelO=0, vowelU=0, vowelY=0;
  int elsePlaceHolder = 0;
  char [] arr = new char[100];
  arr=createArray();
  for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
  {

     if (arr[x] == 'a')
     vowelA++;

     else if (arr[x] == 'e')
     vowelE++;

     else if (arr[x] == 'i')
     vowelI++;

     else if (arr[x] == 'o')
     vowelO++;

     else if (arr[x] == 'u')
     vowelU++;

     else if (arr[x] == 'y')
     vowelY++;

     else
     elsePlaceHolder++;

  }
  System.out.print(vowelA+" "+vowelE+" "+vowelI+" "+vowelO+" "+vowelU+" "+vowelY);
}
```

It will work. Plus you havent initialized those vowel iterators but you have incremented them !

Comment: Thank you for that, the only thing is that I have to have a separate method (createArray()) that creates the 100 character array and outputs the 100 characters.

Comment: Is there anyway for me to keep my createArray() and countArray() method?

Comment: Sorry bro couldn't get what you mean by keep ?
For main function, you just need to:
public static void main(String []as){
 countArray();
}
Inside countArray() you have already called createArray() .

Comment: Sorry, maybe I don't understand your answer correctly. You have me creating the 100 character array in the countArray() method, but I have to have that array created in the createArray() method. 

Or am I reading that wrong, and I just have to alter my countArray() method to be like yours above?

Comment: Never mind, I see that when you create the 100 character array, you call upon the createArray() method to fill it. Thank you for your reply, you fixed my issue.

Comment: Felt glad that it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will create the array once and count the number of elements.

```
char[] chars = createArray();

for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    if(chars[i] == 'a')
        increment number of A's
    else if ...
}
```

instead of creating 5 elements, I'd create an array of size 5 and a would be `arr[0]`, e is `arr[1]` etc.

In your code

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++){
    if(chars[i] == 'a')
        arr[0]++;
    else if(chars[i] == 'e')
        arr[1]++;
    //etc
}
```

Comment: I assume you mean my method createArray(), not generateChar()? And it does work.

So if I am grasping what you are saying, you're saying I don't need my createArray() method? My instructions were to create a method (createArray()) that creates a 100 character array, then output those 100 characters. Then I have to create a method (countArray()) that counts the amount of times each vowel was generated in the array. So I can't omit that method..

Answer (score 0):

hi i just changed your code a little.
hope that helps you.
check this out!

```
private static int vowelA=0;
private static int vowelE=0;
private static int vowelI=0; 
private static int vowelO=0;
private static int vowelU=0;
private static int vowelY=0;
private static int elsePlaceHolder = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {

        char[] chs = createArray();
        System.out.println("vowelA : "+vowelA);
        System.out.println("vowelE : "+vowelE);
        System.out.println("vowelI : "+vowelI);
        System.out.println("vowelO : "+vowelO);
        System.out.println("vowelU : "+vowelU);
        System.out.println("vowelY : "+vowelY);
}

//method to generate random character between ch1 and ch2
   public static char getRandomCharacter(char ch1, char ch2)
   {

      return (char) (ch1 + Math.random() * (ch2 -ch1 +1));

   }

//==========================================   

   //method to assign generated characters (between a and z) to a 100 character array
   public static char[] createArray()
   {

      //declare a 100 character array
      char[] character = new char[100];

      //for loop assigning the random characters to the array using getRandomCharacter method
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++){
      character[x] = getRandomCharacter('a', 'z');
      countArray(character[x]);
      }
      //for loop outputting the characters in the array
      for (int x = 0; x < character.length; x++)
      System.out.println(character[x]);

      return character;

   }

   public static void countArray(char ch)
   {

         if (ch == ('a')){
         vowelA++;}
         else if (ch == 'e'){
         vowelE++;}
         else if (ch == 'i'){
         vowelI++;}
         else if (ch == 'o'){
         vowelO++;}
         else if (ch == 'u'){
         vowelU++;}
         else if (ch == 'y'){
         vowelY++;}
         else{
         elsePlaceHolder++;}
   }
```

Comment: You should explain the code you've posted as your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char[] randomc = new char[]{'a','b','i','i','o','u','u','e','e','e','e','e','e','z','b','f'};
    int[] voweltable = new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // Last element is for non-vowels
    for (int i = 0; i <= randomc.length - 1; i++)
    {
        switch(randomc[i])
        {
            case 'a':
                voweltable[0]++;
                break;
            case 'e':
                voweltable[1]++;
                break;
            case 'i':
                voweltable[2]++;
                break;
            case 'o':
                voweltable[3]++;
                break;
            case 'u':
                voweltable[4]++;
                break;
            default:
                voweltable[5]++;
                break;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= voweltable.length -1; i++)
        System.out.println(voweltable[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as with the `getRandomCharacter()` method, you could try to make use of the int value of the characters and have an int array build for that with the size of the range between `ch1` and `ch2`, then increase the value for each occurrence and then print the count for the vowels, something like:

```
public static void countArray(char ch1, char ch2, char[] character)
    {
        // Create an array with the letters you want to compare with: vowels
        int[] vowels = {(int) 'a', (int) 'e', (int) 'i', (int) 'o', (int) 'u'};

        // Create the array for the range between the two letters
        int[] dictionary = new int[(int) ch2 - (int) ch1 + 1];

        // Fill up the array with the ocurrence of each character
        for(int i = 0; i < character.length; i++){
            dictionary[((int)character[i] - (int) ch1)]++;
        }

        // Print the occurrence of each vowel
        for(int j = 0; j < vowels.length; j++){
            System.out.println((char) vowels[j] + ": " + dictionary[vowels[j] - (int)'a']);
        }
    }
```